# I am trying to use lpad SQL function but it is throwing lpad(text) doesnt exists

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use lpad function but it is throwing lpad(text) doesn't exists in java but it is working perfectly fine when am running the query in Postgres DB.

I have used the below query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
where extract( epoch from to_timestamp(LPAD(CAST (executedDate AS text),8,'0') || LPAD(CAST (executeTime AS text),6,'0'),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) < :ValueinSecounds
```

Here executedDate(int4 datatype) and executeTime(int4 datatype) values are inserted in GMT format in the table.

I need to concate executedDate and executeTime to get the KTI timestamp(that is in seconds).

There as some existing record which has 5 digit in executeTime so used LPAD function.

It is the throwing the below exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function lpad(text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 1381
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2268) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:313) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:109) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2815) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2797) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2629) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2624) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1558) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    ... 40 more***
```

Comment: Can you please add a proper problem statement to your question, ideally along with some sample input/output which explains what you are trying to do here?

Comment: And please format your text and your code properly so it's easier to read.

Comment: this would be **way** easier with a correct data model where `executed_at` is a single `timestamp` column, not some strange integer values. What exactly do those two integer values represent?